# reinforcement learning mini-golf game

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I'm trying to use a reinforcement learning algorithm to play a simple mini-golf game.

- I want to give inputs(angle and force) to a game engine.
- Get the final position of the ball.
- Based on the final position calculate reward.
- Iterate process until success.

I think I can achieve this by using the greedy approach or function approximation. I want to know whether this is possible and want to find a similar example.

Comment: Welcome to SO; unfortunately, your first question ("whether this is possible") is way too broad, and your second one ("to find a similar example") off-topic, as explicitly explained in [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In literature, reinforcement learning is the closest thing to artificial general intelligence, so yes, you can apply it to this mini golf game.

**The following will be the layout:**

**States:** Location of ball on the field (x, y, z)

**Actions:** Angle, Force

**Rewards:** Distance of ball from hole

Depending on how big your field is, this problem should be easily solvable.

> I think I can achieve this by using the greedy approach or function approximation.

You would definitely want to use at least a e-greedy approach to promote exploration in earlier episodes.

To *simplify the problem*, I would consider just a 2D, or maybe even a 1D case first so you get familiar with the algorithm.

For the 1D case, your state would be where along the line your ball is.  Your action is the amount of force applied to the ball.  And the reward can be based off of how far your ball is from the goal post.

I can code this environment for you if you'd like.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use as reward: -1 for each bat, and zero when you meet the hole. This will minimize the number of bats.

Comment: yep that definitely also works since this problem is finite.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply.